# Extending Breeze Entities that don't map to database

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am trying to return and extend a type that is defined in my server data model, but is not contained in the EF DataContext. Using breeze, I am able to return it from the BreezeController, but I cannot call registerEntityTypeCtor with the entity type, because the EntityType is not contained within the metadata.

I would like to be able to extend the model (currently just showing in console as type 'Object') with computed properties for display in an Angular app... Think 'fullName'.

Is there a way to do this within Breeze?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create and add an EntityType directly to the MetadataStore via the MetadataStore.addEntityType method. See the NoDb sample in the Breeze zip for an example of this.

Once you have the EntityType you can then call 'registerEntityTypeCtor'.  If you have 'named' the EntityType consistent with the server side type that will be serialized to the client then Breeze will automatically recognize it.  If not then you can either use the EntityQuery.toType method to force a query result to be recognized as being of your new type or more generally you can create a JsonResultsAdapter to do the same thing.